# Identity Server4, Redirect to MVC client using Google Authentication not working

Tags: google-oauth, identityserver4

I am using Identity server 4 for authentication. When I use my IS4 login then after authentication of the user, user get redirected to the MVC client. But when the user uses Google Authentication for the same MVC client. Then after google authentication user don't get redirected to the MVC client, the user stays on the authentication server's login page?
[image]

Comment: Does your Externalcallback method contain the correct `redirectUrl` parameter?

Comment: Yes redirectionUrl parameter looks like correct, it has correctredirecturi. 

But When I looked info ExternalLoginCallback method in the account controller. The calls comes to this piece of code, where info is null, that's why I guess, it returns back to the login page again.
<code>
        var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (info == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));
        }
</code>
Any suggestions why info can be null?

Comment: You're probably not using the correct scheme
`await HttpContext.Authentication.GetAuthenticateInfoAsync(IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme);` make sure that your SignInScheme in your Startupclass of Google is the same you are trying to access here.

Comment: HttpContext.Authentication.GetAuthenticateInfoAsync method works but having issue to get the providerkey from it for the next line in the flow var result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false);


And this is the flow is given in the MS default mvc core template for

 /Account/ExternalLoginCallback


1. Are we suppose to use it still or it has been changed?

2. And also the await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync(); is given in the MS default template. Did it change?